# Audio bluetooth board. RX and TX?

Tags: usb, audio, bluetooth

Looking at a usb bluetooth audio aux device board I saw RX and TX. What are these points for?[image]

Comment: This is not answerable without seeing another side of the board with recognizable active circuitry, or someone recognizing the product.  From the current image it looks like a dollar-store-special "implausible adapter" that results when entirely incompatible connectors are inexplicably joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serial connection, most likely TTL/UART, possibly used to test and/or reprogram the chip. There should be no need to access them after leaving the factory, but it is less costly to leave them in than to remove them before placing the device in the case.

Comment: Could I used them to rename the board?

Comment: I don't know. The capabilities are determined by the firmware, not the connection.

Comment: Darn That sucks lol, any idea how I can change the name? Or am sol?